# How do I determine the Primary Adapter when using NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()?

Tags: c#, windows, adapter, ip-address

In a C# program I am getting the information for all the adapters using:
NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()

However, how do I determine which one is the primary adapter? I originally thought it was the adapter with the lowest index number but that does not appear to be the case.

Comment: What's the "primary adapter", according to you? Every adapter that's enabled for IP potentially participates in traffic. What you're probably looking for the is the interface connection metric (as exposed by the WMI class [`Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa394217) in `IPConnectionMetric`). As far as I can tell, `System.Net.NetworkInformation` has no way to retrieve that.

Comment: @JeroenMostert thanks for the reply. For example, let's say you have two adapters and they are both connected to the internet.  If you start Internet Explorer, how does it choose which adapter to use?

Comment: It doesn't, that's on a level below IE. IE simply asks the DNS resolver for the IP address of the site, and then starts sending packets. What adapter those packets end up on depends on the route table (`route print` from the command line) and that, in turn, is derived from both the destination network and the interface metrics. (IE does actually have a few "setup internet" thingamajigs and proxy overrides, so this isn't entirely accurate, but this is the general story for network applications that don't do anything special.) It's possible for one application to end up using multiple adapters.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, are you looking for the active adapter through which the connection is made?
I did this:

```
string currentAdapter = "";

foreach (NetworkInterface ni in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()) {
    if (ni.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up
        && ni.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Tunnel
        && ni.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback) {
        currentAdapter = (ni.Name);
    }
}
```

[This solution was found here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a8a2d4aa-afbb-406e-92c7-e12fd6b2a9a2/how-to-check-which-network-adapter-is-connect-to-internet?forum=csharpgeneral&prof=required)